# How to write down proof that if $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\alpha$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-writing, infinity

Let $a, \alpha \in \Bbb{R}$; let $f: (a,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable; let $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\alpha$; let $\beta := \lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$. I want to show that $\beta = 0$. Now, the idea is quite clear to me.

If $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\alpha$ then there is one horizontal assymptote and thus $f$ will get closer to it as $x$ grows. In that case, since it is horizontal, the derivative of $f$ should vanish.

Although the idea is clear I'm not being able to write down this proof. I've tried by contradiction: suppose $\beta > 0$ first. Then since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\alpha$, given $\epsilon > 0$ we have $|f(x)-\alpha|<\epsilon$ as long as $x > M$ for some suitable $M\in \mathbb{R}$, $M > 0$.

Now, if we pick $x > M$ and focus on the interval $(M,x)$ there should be $c$, by the mean value theorem, such that

$$f'(c) = \dfrac{f(x)-f(M)}{x-M}.$$

In this way I can introduce the derivative there, but it is computed at a fixed point. Of course if I vary $x$ the $c$ would vary and I believe I could get a contradiction from this, but I'm not finding how to do this properly.

So how can I write down this idea for this proof? How can I get one contradiction from this?

Comment: Suppose $\beta\ne0$ and consider the quotients $f(x+1)-f(x)\over (x+1)-x$.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: @GudsonChou, $\alpha$ is the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ which is supposed to exist and be finite.

Comment: No restriction on $\alpha$? Any real number?

Comment: @DavidMitra, you mean considering those quotients for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$? In that case, for each $x$ there will be some $c(x)\in (x,x+1)$ such that this quotient is equal to $f'(c(x))$. Then I should use the hypothesis on $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\alpha$ to get one $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x > M$ implies $|f(x)-\alpha|<\epsilon$ and consider what happens then?

Comment: Yes @GudsonChou, there is no restriction on $\alpha$. It can be any real number.

Comment: The quotients have limit zero at infinity, by the limit condition on $f$. This would contradict that the assumption that limit of $f'$ at infinity is non-zero.

Comment: Now I've got it. Thanks @DavidMitra!

Comment: There are certainly differentiable $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ but such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist. An example is $\frac{\sin x^2}x$, which I recommend graphing.

Comment: The question as it stands is wrong. It should be reworded to something like this: If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \alpha$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = \beta$ then $\beta = 0$. The original question here does not say whether the limit of $f'(x)$ exists or not. Rather from the heading it looks like the existence of limit of $f'(x)$ is a conclusion based on existence of limit of $f(x)$. This is not true in general. See the example by @AkivaWeinberger.

Comment: Once the question is corrected as mentioned in my previous comment, it is clear that by mean value theorem we have $f(x + 1) - f(x) = f'(\xi)$ with $x < \xi < x + 1$ and letting $x \to \infty$ we see that $\xi \to \infty$ and $\alpha - \alpha = \beta$ so that $\beta = 0$.

Comment: Writing down "$β:=\lim_{x→∞}f′(x)$" as part of the assumptions contains the statement of the existence of the limit. The title should not be taken as source since the longer statement directly below corrects it.

Comment: @LutzL: Ok got your point. let's get a confirmation from OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider (as proposed by David Mitra in the comments)
$$
f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)-n}=f'(n+\theta_n),\qquad \theta_n\in(0,1)
$$ 
Now we know that the limits on both sides exist by the assumptions of the statement. The limit on the left is $α-α=0$, the limit on the right $β$ as $c_n=n+\theta_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Wrong without the additional hypothesis $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists.

Comment: This is implicit in the assumptions in the definition of $β$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the additional condition suggested by Paramanand Singh and L'Hôpital (version [anything/inf](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0002989051005.di991759.99p01956.pdf), see the *second* page):
$$0 = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x = \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)= \beta.$$